measure distance between nearest points on a road
I have a layer of multistrings (main roads) and another layer of points (houses/buildings etc)
I want to the check if the distance between point A and point B alongside a specific road is less than 10 kms away.
But my problem is that these points don't necessarily overlaps or intersects those roads, they are within some distance (less than 500 meters) away over a secondary street (i have no data of those interior streets).
So, i think I should find the nearest point over the road of the point A and B (lets say point C and D) with a limit of 500 meters and then check if these points C and D are within X km of distance alongside the road.
Im a rookie in geo-coding in R so im pretty lost. I have failed  using, for example, st_nearest_point (it brings me the closest point of every segment of the multistring)
Here is a rough draft, thanks in advance!


I believe you may be looking for a {sfnetworks} based workflow:

first st_network_blend to snap your points to the main road, and then
followed then by a st_network_paths call to find the shortest path between your points

